# async(non-blocking) php verification of id_token on google signing

Tags: php, asynchronous, google-signin

Implementing php verification of id_token on google signing.
But I need to do it with async/non-blocking execution (under reactphp).

Checking official client ("google/apiclient": "2.14") but it verifyIdToken use under hood guzzle (7.4.5) as httpClient (must be only for getting keys I think).

What is the proper way to verify google id_token in async/non-blocking mode of execution?

Comment: https://amphp.org/http-client, probably, together with amphp's general ability to do non-blocking asynchronous work. I haven't tried it personally but it's worth experimenting with

Comment: Or maybe https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/5.3/clients.html#asynchronous-requests is sufficient for you